# Why is method annotated with @PrePersist not called on @Entity class with @IdClass?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cockroachdb

Why is method annotated with `@PrePersist` not called when persisting class annotated with `@Entity` and `@IdClass`?

#### Folder (entity)

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@IdClass(Folder.FolderId.class)
@Table(name = "folder", schema = "my_schema")
public class Folder {
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class FolderId implements Serializable {
        private UUID driveId;
        private String folderId;
    }

    @Id
    private UUID driveId;

    @Id
    private String folderId;

    @Column
    private String parentFolderId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column
    private Instant createdAt;

    @Column
    private Instant updatedAt;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        this.setCreatedAt(now);
        this.setUpdatedAt(now);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        this.setUpdatedAt(Instant.now());
    }
}
```

#### FolderRepository (repo)

```
@Repository
public interface FolderRepository extends JpaRepository<Folder, String> {
}
```

#### FolderService (service)

```java
@Transactional
public void saveFolder(Folder folderToSave, String updatedBy) {
    folderToSave.setUpdatedBy(updatedBy);
    return folderRepository.saveAndFlush(folderToSave);
}
```

I have a non-null constraint on `createdAt` which is being violated since `@PrePersist` is not being invoked.

Comment: Don't you also need the createdBy set? It is marked nullable=false but doesn't follow the same pattern as the updatedBy so might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: I always manually set createdBy and updatedBy higher up and can confirm the only problematic field is createdAt. The `@PreUpdate` hook is getting called. It's just the `@PrePersist` hook is not getting called I assume since it has a composite key that is never null and not generated by the DB so it doesn't know when to invoke

Comment: Verify it actually isn't called with println or debugging, as if it isn't, it is a Hibernate bug. Using Spring 'save' might be playing a part, as it under the covers tries to determine if the entity is new to call either persist or Merge which have different mechanics. Both should trigger the prePersist on your entity, but I suspect your other entities are having persist called on them while for this one, merge is used. You can see on another entity by pre-assigning PK values, or manually calling merge on your other entities to see if prePersist is still called with them.

Answer (score 0):

probably the two methods should be public

```
   @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        this.setCreatedAt(now);
        this.setUpdatedAt(now);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.setUpdatedAt(Instant.now());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the methods need to be public. I have protected methods on other classes that don't use `@IdClass` and they are ALWAYS getting called. So it's something to do with the `@IdClass` and not the public/protected I believe

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `@PrePersist` is only called when the record is created. Updating an existing record won't trigger this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).